# Charged Black Hole in 1+2 dimensions without cosmological constant

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, black-holes, charge

Does a charged black hole in 2+1D exist? I am interested in a theory of the form:

$$ S = \int d^3 x \sqrt{-g}\big(\cfrac{R}{2} - \cfrac{1}{2}F^2\big) $$

where $F^2 = F_{ab}F^{ab}$.

The field equations are:

$$G_{ab} = 2T_{ab} $$
$$\nabla^{a}F_{ab}=0$$

Imposing a one degree of freedom metric:

$$ds^2 = -f(r)dt^2 + f^{-1}(r)dr^2 + r^2 d\theta^2 $$

and an ansatz for the $U(1)$ field:

$$A_{a} = (-\phi(r),0,0).$$

Maxwell's equations can be immediately integrated to yield:

$$ \phi(r) = c_1\ln(r) +c_2 $$

I cannot find any mistakes in my calculation, neither any paper on 2+1D charged black holes without cosmological constant. If i am correct what does $c_1$ and $c_2$ represent? Why the potential does not vanish at infinity?

Comment: Looks like you are asking for the **BTZ** Black hole : https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9204099.  It is a solution of Einstein-Maxwell equations in 2+1 spacetime dimensions, with a negative cosmological constant.

Comment: I am aware of the BTZ Black Hole but if you read my question carefully i am asking for a solution without cosmological constant.

Comment: I apologise for being too sloppy

Comment: How did you find Maxwell's equations without a metric? Normally, you would have to solve Einstein's and Maxwell's equations simultaneously. I'll give it a shot

Comment: Τhe unknown functions cancel out for a one degree of freedom metric, something that does not happen for a two degrees of freedom metric. It's easy, if you have troubles i can give you same hints.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My apologies for reading/answering too quickly. In the absence of a cosmological constant, the *vacuum* Einstein equations do not support a black hole solution in 2+1 dimensions, but the *electrovacuum* Einstein equations do.

The solution you're looking for is described in [this paper by Deser and Mazur](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0264-9381/2/3/003).  The metric due to a point source with charge $e$ and mass $m$ takes the form

$$ds^2 = \left(1-\frac{Ge^2}{1-4Gm} \log(r)\right)^2 dt^2 +\exp\left[Ge^2\log(r)^2 - 8Gm\log(r)\right](dr^2+r^2d\theta^2)$$

which exhibits a Killing horizon (not an event horizon) at $r=\exp\left[\frac{1-4Gm}{Ge^2}\right]$

---

The electrostatic potential you refer to is the same as one obtains for an infinitely long wire in 3+1 dimensions.  In $d+1$ dimensions, the electric field from a point charge goes like $1/r^{d-1}$, which means that the potential goes like $1/r^{d-2}$ if $d\neq 2$, and $\log(r)$ for $d=2$.

Physically, this simply means that if you started a test charge at rest and let it be pushed out to infinity by the electric field, then its kinetic energy would grow without bound as it traveled further and further away. The reason this feature does not emerge in 3 or more spatial dimensions is that the electric field falls off sufficiently quickly that the kinetic energy of the aforementioned test charge remains bounded.

Comment: So you're saying that Einstein's equations i wrote are wrong?? The Ricci Tensor is zero, if we consider no matter, but here i am considering the electromagnetic stress tensor.

Comment: The Weyl tensor vanishes by definition but the Ricci tensor does not vanish. This is my whole point.

Comment: -1 OP clearly asks for an electrovacuum solution, not a vacuum solution. There's no a priori reason for the solution to be flat without a cosmological constant

Comment: @VladimirA Yes indeed I misunderstood. I'll have to consider this for a while.

Comment: @J.Murray Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

The electric field is given by the derivative of the potential $\phi(r)$ which indeed vanishes at infinity.

Comment: Shouldn't the scalar potential also vanish at infinity?

Comment: Why do you say that? Scalar potential can always be shifted by a constant. It’s a special case of gauge transformation.

Comment: I know that. But a constant is a constant we can set zero. In 4 dimension the scalar potential turns out to be $A/r$, which has qualitative differences from a logarithmic behavior and also vanishes at infinity. So there is the point my question comes from. Why in 4-d the scalar potential vanishes while in 3-d it does not???